# Closing behavior

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

During the last couple weeks I came across a considerable amount of questions that have been close-voted due to not being specific to WordPress.

Approximately 9 out of 10 times I agreed in that the questions were not WP-specific per se - so I voted the same, after having read the question (and comments, if present).

However, the questions themselves were oftentimes *accurate* and good-worded - and definitley worth being answered. So I wondered why they have been close-voted as *not specific to WordPress* and not as *belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network* (which most of the times has been the case, IMO).

I'm aware that moderators (like all users having enough reputation) are being notified of close-voted questions. So if a moderator sees a question that better were asked on another SE site, it could/will be migrated.
Nevertheless, I'm confident in that more of these question could be migrated if they weren't close-voted as *not WP-specific* but close-voted as *should be on StackOverflow*, for instance.

I must say that I, too, close-voted a bunch of questions as off-topic (because **they were**, and the description even says *Might be better asked at Stack Overflow or other appropriate site of Stack Exchange network.*). A few seconds later, however, I thought about having voted as *belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network* would have been the better decision.

What do you think?

Does it matter (to you) how/if a question asked on WPSE in the first place while better put on SO, for instance, gets attention (and a solution)?

Does it matter if a question is close-voted as *belongs to StackOverflow*, or *not WP-specific* (what IMO puts more *weight* on the moderators' shoulders than just approving to migrate a question to an already suggested site)?

Maybe the option *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network* doesn't stick out enough (as it could/should) - as a one-liner, no color/links and the like...?

Answer (score 5):

I sometimes vote to migrate, but many of the question I vote to close already have 20 functional duplicates on Stack Overflow, for example. I see no reason to clutter another site with migrated duplicates. I think that that is the key, at least for me.

Think about how many "I don't know how to access a PHP array/object" questions there are, or "my CSS doesn't work". The latter nearly always "too localized" anyway.

After thinking about it, I think it boils down to I only vote to migrate otherwise good questions to other sites. Questions with multiple problems I tend to just vote to close.

Also, the list of site choices to migrate to is pretty limited. There are a rare few I would have voted to migrate had the migration list included a few more options.

Comment: I agree with you in that there's no reason to _clutter another site duplicates_. However, the question/duplicate **A)** is already there (here on WPSE, that is), and **B)** as I stated in my question, the description of the close-vote says _Might be better asked at Stack Overflow or other appropriate site of Stack Exchange network_, which might lead to the question being asked on that other site, again - while it's already here, in addition to the, say, 20 functional duplicates...

Comment: Maybe I should have said something like "I only vote to migrate otherwise good questions to other sites. Questions with multiple problems I tend to just vote to close."

Answer (score 5):

Some of these questions are from users who are question banned on Stack Overflow. We just cannot migrate those questions. And I send only good questions to SO or another site. Not just barely acceptable, but really good.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about these bans. I also didn't mean to say that not enough questions are migrated. So I wasn't adressing this at you moderators. I just thought that maybe more questions could be migrated (and thus get solved) if there were more questions voted to be migrated. I hope this makes sense...